# How to make the security rule is True by default in odoo res.uesrs form?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, security, odoo

i have created a model positions ,and add a field Many2one to res.users model that related to positions, also i added a security groups 
all i need is when i select a position, some of Boolean fields of security Groups set True

i'am inherit res.users and try to override on Boolean fields  and add attrs default = True

```
class autouser(models.Model):

_inherit = 'res.users'

position = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="positions", string="Autoparts position", required=False, )
in_group_86 = fields.Boolean(string="sakdajklsdj",dafault=True )
```

there is no changes happens

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the default groups for a new user you should:
- go to the list of users
- search for inactive users (active is false)
- open the user "Default User Template"
- edit the groups as you wish

Then, any newly created users will have the same groups as the default user template :)